# How to use a type variable without using "any" in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I have a function:

```
 const withHeadElement = (renderHoc: Function) => (options: Options) => (other, params) => something
```

but I want `options :Options` to be of the type of the parameter passed to the renderHOC to make it more generic. In the above example, renderHoc is just typed as a function, how can I change that so it's typed as `(renderHOC: (param: TYPE) => ReturnTYPE) => (options: TYPE) ....`  or something like that.

Is this a use-case for generics? if so how can I do the above

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
const withHeadElement = <T extends (args: Parameters<T>[0]) => ReturnType<T>>(renderHoc: T): (options: Parameters<T>[0]) => ReturnType<T> => {
    return renderHoc
}
```

There is a native util type called `Parameters<T>`, which is what you are looking for I think

And better would be to extract that generic type and reuse it later. Like

```
type RenderHoc = {
    <T extends (args: Parameters<T>[0]) => ReturnType<T>>(renderHoc: T): (options: Parameters<T>[0]) => ReturnType<T>
}

const withHeadElement : RenderHoc = (renderHoc) => renderHoc
```

And notice that I am getting params by `[0]` , because Parameters return array of params.